# How to implement AsyncCallback when importing rows?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ado.net

I never used `AsyncCallback`. Need your help.

When In Windows Form app I importing rows application form freezes. To prevent it, i think I can use `AsyncCallback`.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in srcdt.Rows)
{
    desdt.ImportRow(dr);
}
```

and while importing rows, to show in `lebel.Text` imported row count.
Some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

This will allow you to kick off your long running process in another thread, receive progress reports and a completed event.